# How could I bring the highlighted text to the very next line with a left-alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}


\begin{document}
Proof:
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
E&=&\times \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{m\,\text{factors}}\div \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{n\,\text{factors}};\,\text{(Definition of an index)}\\
&=&\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm \times a \div a\div a\div a \dotsm \div a;\,\text{(The law of association for multiplication and division)}\\
&=&\times (\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm m-n\,\text{factors})\\
&&\times (a\div a)\times (a\div a)\times \dotsm n\,\text{factors};\,\text{(The laws of commutation and association)}\\    
&=&\times \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{m-n\,\text{factors}};\,\text{(Properties of division)}\\
E&=&a^{m-n}.\,\text{(Definition of an index)}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `IEEEtranstools` is not standard LaTeX, I show it below without it.  I just move the comment to its own row, and `\rlap` it, followed by a phantom `E`.

EDITED to add extra empty groups `{}` to make the `\times` a binary operator, as needed.

As Runar points out in a comment, in the absence of `IEEEtranstool`, the `eqnarray` method shown below would not be preferred, but rather one of the `align` environments of `amsmath`.  So below, I show both approaches.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
Proof:
\vspace{-1em}
%\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\begin{eqnarray*}
E&=&\times \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{m\,\text{factors}}\div \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{n\,\text{factors}};\,\text{(Definition of an index)}\\
&=&{}\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm \times a \div a\div a\div a \dotsm \div a;\\
 \rlap{(The law of association for multiplication and division)}\phantom{E}& \\
&=&{}\times (\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm m-n\,\text{factors})\\
&&{}\times (a\div a)\times (a\div a)\times \dotsm n\,\text{factors};\,\text{(The laws of commutation and association)}\\    
&=&{}\times \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{m-n\,\text{factors}};\,\text{(Properties of division)}\\
E&=&a^{m-n}.\,\text{(Definition of an index)}
\end{eqnarray*}
%\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\begin{align*}
E&=\times \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{m\,\text{factors}}\div \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{n\,\text{factors}};\,\text{(Definition of an index)}\\
&={}\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm \times a \div a\div a\div a \dotsm \div a;\\
 \rlap{(The law of association for multiplication and division)}\phantom{E}& \\
&={}\times (\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm m-n\,\text{factors})\\
&\phantom{{}={}}{}\times (a\div a)\times (a\div a)\times \dotsm n\,\text{factors};\,\text{(The laws of commutation and association)}\\    
&={}\times \underbrace{(\times a\times a\times a\times \dotsm)}_{m-n\,\text{factors}};\,\text{(Properties of division)}\\
E&=a^{m-n}.\,\text{(Definition of an index)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `eqnarray` should be avoided. [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/89976)